# Connect 2+ strings to 1 string

Tags: c++, mysql, string

When I try to connect string objects with other strings i'll get a "basic_string" which is not accepted by my method.

I got the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘Class1::doSomething(std::__cxx11::basic_string)’

My main class:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s = "test";
    Class1* class1 = new Class1();
    class1->doSomething("some text " + s + " too");
}
```

My "class1":

```
using namespace std;
class Class1 {
     public:
         void doSomething(const char* sql) { 
              mysqli_query(connection, sql);
         }
}
```

Why I can't just "+" the strings together?

Comment: _"`Class1 class1 = new Class1();`"_ You meant `Class1* class1 = new Class1();`, right? Otherwise this doesn't compile for a different reason. But better to drop that dynamic allocation altogether.....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.

The error is not related to the `+`.

The error is because you are passing a `std::string` to a function that wants a `const char*`, and the two things are not the same.

Fixable, though, because `std::string` has a member function [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) that gives you a C-style string out of its contents, precisely for this kind of occasion:

```
class1->doSomething(("some text " + s + " too").c_str());
```

As an aside, a minimal example would have been:

```
std::string str = "hi";
Class1 class1;
class1.doSomething(str);
```

Then you would have known already that the `+` were unrelated.

If `Class1` is yours, you may find it more idiomatic to allow your class to accept a C++ string, only "converting" for the MySQL API when necessary:

```
void doSomething(const std::string& sql) {
    doSomething(sql.c_str());
}

void doSomething(const char* sql) { 
    mysqli_query(connection, sql);
}
```

*(I've kept the original overload because if you originally had a C-string, constructing a `std::string` just for this function call would be wasteful.)*

Now your original usage is fine.

Comment: I'd rather change signature of `Class1::doSomething` to accept `std::string` and use `sql.c_str()` in the method instead. Also, I'd note that [using namespace `std` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @Zereges: Jinx! :)

Comment: @Zereges could be a pessimization.

Comment: I would say, `std::string_view` :)

Comment: @SergeyA: Okay, fair enough, that's a good call. I have heard of that but am not a C++17er (or C++20, whatever)

Comment: LRiO, not the way you've done it, but this is not how I understood Zerges's suggestion.